# How can I get my output to be separated by commas based on user input from scanner?

Tags: java

I have a class which takes keyboard input, how could I go about making it so that it can take multiple double and char inputs on one line e.g. 1   2  a a a to then get the output:

"1","2","a","a","a" by splitting it into separate strings? this is  what I've done so far:

```
public class MyInputInfo implements Comparable <MyInputInfo> {

public static double numeric;
public static char symbol;

public MyInputInfo(double numeric, char symbol) {
    this.numeric = numeric;
    this.symbol = symbol;

}
public static char getSymbol() {
    int asciiValue = 97;

    for (int i = asciiValue; i <= 122; i++) {
        String convertedChar = Character.toString ((char) i);
        System.out.println (convertedChar);
    }
    return symbol;
}
@Override
public int compareTo(MyInputInfo o) {
    if (this.numeric < o.numeric) {
        return 1;
    } else if (this.getSymbol( ) < o.getSymbol ( )) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Numeric " + numeric + " Symbol " + symbol;
   }

}
```

the class im working on right now

```
import java.util.*;


public class MyKeyboardInput {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

    MyInputInfo.numeric = s.nextDouble();

    MyInputInfo.symbol = s.next ( ).charAt (0);

    System.out.println (MyInputInfo.numeric+ "," + MyInputInfo.symbol);




        }
    }
```

I'm new to java so apologies for coming off as slow. All help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you expecting to loop X number of times to collect numbers and characters from user?

Comment: Since i'm trying to collect keyboard inputs from the user I guess there would be an amount expected so the numbers on the keyboard plus symbols such as the alphabet or , ! @ . etc.

Comment: You should remove `this.` from your constructor. In fact, you should remove the constructor altogether since it doesn't make sense with static-only fields. Also, the `compareTo` method will always return 0 since `this.numeric` and `o.numeric` will always be the same and `this.getSymbol()` and `o.getSymbol()` will always be the same.

Comment: I could argue the `MyInputInfo` class is not really needed. At least not for this problem. @AishatTaylor is my answer satisfactory or do you need to group all the numbers and characters together regardless of input order?

Comment: How should I go about fixing my compareTo method as I tried to do it so it would sort numerical values before character inputs? sorry if code seems all over the place this is just some java exercises I'm doing. Also the MyInputInfo class is there because I need to store whether the keyboad inputs are numerical or char values. and my toString method is there for later usage in another class.

Comment: @AishatTaylor to sort, create two tables, one for numbers and one for characters, and reuse the logic of the second solution. You can then work on adding the elements of each list into a `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Obtain numbers and chars in predictable order
2. Obtain numbers and chars in random order

### Obtain numbers and chars in predictable order

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of iterations: ");
    int count = scanner.nextInt();
    
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.print("\nEnter a floating point number: ");
        buffer.append(scanner.nextDouble() + " ");
        System.out.print("\nEnter a character: ");
        buffer.append(scanner.next().charAt(0) + " ");
    }
    scanner.close();
    String output = buffer.toString().trim().replaceAll(" ", ", ");
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

If you enter `1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5 e`, the output will look like this

```
1.0, a, 2.0, b, 3.0, c, 4.0, d, 5.0, e
```

It's really that simple. The key is to use `StringBuilder` to "stage" the input and then convert all of the individual inputs into a single `String` output. To make it easier to remove the last comma, I just separated the entries by spaces, trimmed the string to remove the last space, and then prepended the remaining spaces with a comma.

### Obtain numbers and chars in random order

This solution is similar, but in this case, just capture the input as a `String` and then figure out if the input is numeric or not. If it is not numeric, then it is a character.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of iterations: ");
    int count = scanner.nextInt();
    
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.print("\nEnter a number or character: ");
        String s = scanner.next();
        try {
            Double num = Double.parseDouble(s);
            buffer.append(num + " ");
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            buffer.append(s.charAt(0) + " ");
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
    String output = buffer.toString().trim().replaceAll(" ", ", ");
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

### Caveats

You need to figure out what to do when something like "character" is provided as input. As you can see in the code, the code captures only `charAt(0)`. This might or might not be correct for your use. But, this is *typically* how it is portrayed on the web *how to get character from Scanner in Java*.

Also, there is no error handling on the first solution if the input is not a number. You could try to prompt again if the character entered is not a number. Likewise, when prompted to enter a character, what happens if the input is a number? You will need to tweak the code to do what you want. With the second approach, you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: This answer is perfect, thank you so much for your help! really appreciate it.